# Ajax/php contact form sending blank emails from time to time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, contact-form

Well I have this contact form that sends blank emails. But I did some testing and it doesn't happens to me. The only way this could happen, I think, would be by accesing the .php file directly. If not I don't know what could be the problem. The form doesn't let you send a blank email. If this keeps happening I'm going to add a validation in the php file too, but until I find out what is the problem I don't want to ignore this messages.

This is the HTML

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="/contactEngine.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <input title="Input name" type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Nombre:" required="">
        <input title="Input email" placeholder="Email:" type="email" name="Email" id="Email" required="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject:" name="Subjet" id="Subjet">
        <textarea title="Input message" placeholder="Mensaje:" name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message" required=""></textarea>
        <input title="Input result" placeholder="25 + 25 = ?" type="text" name="Captcha" id="Captcha" required="">
        <p id="wrongCaptcha"> Try again </p> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="submit-button"> 
</form>
```

This is the JS

```
function validateForm(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var x = document.forms["contactForm"]["Captcha"].value; 
if (x != 50) {//if captcha is wrong
    $("#Captcha").addClass("wrongCaptchaEntered");
    $("#Captcha").css("animation-name" , "none");
    setTimeout (function(){
        $("#Captcha").css("animation-name" , "changeBorder");
    },100);
    if ($("#wrongCaptcha").css("display") == "none"){
        $("#wrongCaptcha").slideDown();
    }   
}
else {  //if captcha is correct 
    var formAction = $("#contactForm").attr("action");  
    if (formAction == "/contactEngine.php"){
        var formData = $("#contactForm").serialize();
        $.post( formAction, formData, function(data){
            console.log (data);
            $(".formulario").changeTo({content: "<h2 class='section-title BackgroundGradientBlack'>"+ data +"</h2>"});
        });
    }
}
return false;
}
```

And the PHP

```
<?php
$EmailFrom = "EmailFrom@test.com";
$EmailTo = "EmailTo@test.com";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Subject = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Subjet']));    
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 


$email_content = "Frontpage";
$email_content .= "\nNombre: $Name";
$email_content .= "\nEmail: $Email";
$email_content .= "\nMotivo: $Subject";
$email_content .= "\nMensaje: $Message";


$email_headers = "From: <$EmailFrom>";


if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
    http_response_code(200);
    echo "Mensaje enviado";
} else {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably some bot that's testing the PHP endpoint it can see in your JS and is sending data to it, trying to cause havoc. I bet if you logged the $_POST variable every time an email was sent, you'd seen a lot of spammy nonsense in some $_POST variables. Emails are blank just because the bots aren't smart enough to know which keys to use in its POSTs.